# Checkout payment hook in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a markup, `<h3>payment</h3>`, above the payment methods section in the checkout page.

I tried inserting in files `woocommerce/checkout/payment.php`, `woocommerce/checkout/payment-method.php` and `woocommerce/checkout/checkout.php`.

Regardless where I insert the markup, it will replicate.

[image]

Where should I add the markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the hook for that area. Place it in your *functions.php* file:

```
function woocommerce_before_payment_area( ) { 
    echo '<h3>payment</h3>';
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'woocommerce_before_payment_area', 50, 0 );
```

If it is still doubling up then the hook might already be in your theme. Search your code base for `woocommerce_review_order_before_payment` and change it there.